# IBM Watson conversation: How to access JSON object from context variable?

Tags: json, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I made a chatbot which takes 'place' as input and connects to an external API service passing the 'place' as a parameter. The API service returns a list of all available airport details for the given place as a JSON object.

For example, if 'Berlin' is given as input in conversation, The API returns following JSON object, which is then stored in the context variable $TheResult, 
The context variable $TheResult holds the following JSON object as the value when the input is 'Berlin',

```
{
  "message": {
    "Places": [
      {
        "CityId": "BERL-sky",
        "CountryId": "DE-sky",
        "CountryName": "Germany",
        "PlaceId": "BERL-sky",
        "PlaceName": "Berlin",
        "RegionId": ""
      },
      {
        "CityId": "BERL-sky",
        "CountryId": "DE-sky",
        "CountryName": "Germany",
        "PlaceId": "TXL-sky",
        "PlaceName": "Berlin Tegel",
        "RegionId": ""
      },
      {
        "CityId": "BERL-sky",
        "CountryId": "DE-sky",
        "CountryName": "Germany",
        "PlaceId": "SXF-sky",
        "PlaceName": "Berlin Schoenefeld",
        "RegionId": ""
      },
      {
        "CityId": "BTVA-sky",
        "CountryId": "US-sky",
        "CountryName": "United States",
        "PlaceId": "BTV-sky",
        "PlaceName": "Burlington",
        "RegionId": "VT"
      },
      {
        "CityId": "BLIA-sky",
        "CountryId": "US-sky",
        "CountryName": "United States",
        "PlaceId": "BLI-sky",
        "PlaceName": "Bellingham",
        "RegionId": "WA"
      },
      {
        "CityId": "BRLA-sky",
        "CountryId": "US-sky",
        "CountryName": "United States",
        "PlaceId": "BRL-sky",
        "PlaceName": "Burlington",
        "RegionId": "IA"
      }
    ]
  },
  "parameters": {
    "context": "",
    "message": "",
    "service": "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/autosuggest/v1.0/FI/EUR/en-US/?query=Berlin"
  }
}
```

When I use the respond text as `Response from external server: $TheResult.message.Places`, it generates the following output,

> Response from external server:
>   [{"CityId":"BERL-sky","CountryId":"DE-sky","CountryName":"Germany","PlaceId":"BERL-sky","PlaceName":"Berlin","RegionId":""},{"CityId":"BERL-sky","CountryId":"DE-sky","CountryName":"Germany","PlaceId":"TXL-sky","PlaceName":"Berlin
>   Tegel","RegionId":""},{"CityId":"BERL-sky","CountryId":"DE-sky","CountryName":"Germany","PlaceId":"SXF-sky","PlaceName":"Berlin
>   Schoenefeld","RegionId":""},{"CityId":"BTVA-sky","CountryId":"US-sky","CountryName":"United
>   States","PlaceId":"BTV-sky","PlaceName":"Burlington","RegionId":"VT"},{"CityId":"BLIA-sky","CountryId":"US-sky","CountryName":"United
>   States","PlaceId":"BLI-sky","PlaceName":"Bellingham","RegionId":"WA"},{"CityId":"BRLA-sky","CountryId":"US-sky","CountryName":"United
>   States","PlaceId":"BRL-sky","PlaceName":"Burlington","RegionId":"IA"}]

I have to access the first 'CityId' from the JSON object and display it as the output, in the case of Berlin as input, the expected output is,

> The first airport city id is: BERL-sky

I tried the respond text, `The first airport city id is: $TheResult.message.Places.CityId`
it throws following dialog node error

> Error when updating output with output of dialog
>   node id [node_1_1551877430730]. Node output is
>   [{"generic":[{"values":[{"text":"Response from external server:
>   $TheResult.message.Places.CityId"}],"response_type":"text","selection_policy":"sequential"}]}]
>   SpEL evaluation error: Expression [ $TheResult.message.Places.CityId ]
>   converted to [ context['TheResult'].message.Places.CityId ] at
>   position 37: EL1008E: Property or field 'CityId' cannot be found on
>   object of type 'JsonArray' - maybe not public?

and the respond text,`The first airport city id is: $TheResult.message.Places[0].CityId` also didn't work. It didn't generate any error, but displays the same output as above only appending extra [0].CityId at the end.

> The first airport city id is:
>   [{"CityId":"BERL-sky","CountryId":"DE-sky","CountryName":"Germany","PlaceId":"BERL-sky","PlaceName":"Berlin","RegionId":""},{"CityId":"BERL-sky","CountryId":"DE-sky","CountryName":"Germany","PlaceId":"TXL-sky","PlaceName":"Berlin
>   Tegel","RegionId":""},{"CityId":"BERL-sky","CountryId":"DE-sky","CountryName":"Germany","PlaceId":"SXF-sky","PlaceName":"Berlin
>   Schoenefeld","RegionId":""},{"CityId":"BTVA-sky","CountryId":"US-sky","CountryName":"United
>   States","PlaceId":"BTV-sky","PlaceName":"Burlington","RegionId":"VT"},{"CityId":"BLIA-sky","CountryId":"US-sky","CountryName":"United
>   States","PlaceId":"BLI-sky","PlaceName":"Bellingham","RegionId":"WA"},{"CityId":"BRLA-sky","CountryId":"US-sky","CountryName":"United
>   States","PlaceId":"BRL-sky","PlaceName":"Burlington","RegionId":"IA"}][0].CityId

How should I parse this JSON object to access the individual key-value pairs?

Thanks in advance, I can elaborate the question further if necessary!!

Comment: You use CityID in the response, but the JSON data says CityId. Did you try it with CityId...?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake while writing the question here, I double checked with CityId for both variations with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your JSON path expression into the [expression syntax](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods). There you can use the full syntax. Something like this:

```
The first airport code is <? $TheResult.message.Places[0].CityId ?>
```